# unique indexes throwing: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have a list of DataFrames. When trying to append them I get:

```bash
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid
with uniquely valued Index objects
```

However, my indexes are unique, example:

```py
dfList[0].index
Index(['5560654070'], dtype='object')

fList[1].index
Index(['5562221068'], dtype='object')
```

When `append()`, or `concat()`, both give the error above.

```py
dfList[0].append(dfList[1])

"""
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
"""
```

I have tried `reset_index()` as well as `ignore_index=True`, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Found the reason for the errors. As somewhat of a pandas noob I thought the error only had to do with the index. However the problem was that I had duplicate columns in each DataFrame.

Comment: would be nice if this answer had more detail.

Comment: That should not be the answer, as mentioned in this post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/69929377/6510273

Comment: @FloridaMan , the problem is when only one of the df has duplicated columns, the post you mention, makes reference to a couiple of dataframes that have identical column index with duplicated column names.

Comment: I just had this problem and this answer provided the insight I need to figure it out. It should be more upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was alignment of columns in two dfs is not consistent, after correct column position problem solved.
hope it helps someone suffer same, I did not find similar answer, strange hehe.
using pandas 1.0.1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

#Try:

```
dfList[0].index
Index(['5560654070'], dtype='object')

dfList[1].index
Index(['5562221068'], dtype='object')

dfList_new = dfList[0:2]
```