# Pandas Concat returning "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes with the same headers.
When I try to concatenate (`pd.concat()`) these two dfs (df1, df2), I get the error:

```
"InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"
```

I figured out that the problem is that there are duplicate column names within each dataframe.
Example:

**df1**

```
respondent ID - Column1 - Column2 - Column3 - Column1 - Column2 - Column3
```

**df2**

```
respondent ID - Column1 - Column2 - Column3 - Column1 - Column2 - Column3
```

in theory, I just want to add the data of df2 below df1 (without the headers of df2 ofc)

How do I bypass this? Any thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: append dataframe to another df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39815646/pandas-append-dataframe-to-another-df)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicated columns shouldn't be an issue (even with `ignore_index=False`):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([range(7)], columns=['respondent ID', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2']*7], columns=['respondent ID', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
  respondent ID Column1 Column2 Column3 Column1 Column2 Column3
0             0       1       2       3       4       5       6
1             2       2       2       2       2       2       2
```

Comment: The problem is when duplicated columns are in only one dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
df1 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: that returns: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'